# How to receive XML Messages from IBM Websphere MQ in Spring MVC and display a message as successful or unsuccessful?

Tags: spring-mvc, ibm-mq

Please Provide me the syntax in spring mvc to receive xml message and to display a success message if received or else display a failure message if message is not received
    `@GetMapping("recv") 
    String recv()
    { 
    try{ 
    return jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("DEV.QUEUE.1").toString(); 
    return "SUCCESS";
    }
    catch(JmsException ex)
    { 
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return "FAIL";
    }
    }`

This code is for JSON file format but I need to send XML file from spring mvc to IBM WebSphere MQ

Comment: It would be better if you provide the code snippets you used to try

Comment: I got this syntax on net but this syntax was for receiving json messages @GetMapping("recv")
String recv(){
    try{
        return jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("DEV.QUEUE.1").toString();  
   return "SUCCESS";                                                                                            }catch(JmsException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "FAIL";
    }
}                                                                                                                 Please help me out with xml message receiving format from IBM mq using spring

Comment: Edit and add the code you have tried,  including any attempts to make it do what you want to the actual question,  not in comments.

Comment: Receiving an XML message is exactly the same as receiving a JSON message.  What you do with it after you receive it, is the different part.  As JoshMc said, post the code of what you have tried.